# PHP prepend class names with sub-space for autoloading

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I'm just wrapping my head around PHP namespaces and autoloading with composer. I have a question about the following code:

```
namespace APP\Controllers;

use APP;
use APP\Interfaces;
use APP\Lib;

class      PageController 
extends    Lib\ActionController 
implements Interfaces\ControllerInterface 
{
    //stuff
}
```

Why do I have to prepend the extends class with the sub-space with 'Lib\' when I already use the line 'use APP\Lib;'? Same goes for the interface. When I don't prepend I get an autoload error. I'm using composer to autoload and have this in my composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "APP":        "app/"
    }
}
```

In app/ I have subfolders Lib, Interfaces and Controllers like so:

```
/app
    /Controllers
    /Interfaces
    /Lib
```

I noticed that in other devs code they don't have to do this. I'm confused as to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including three namespaces:

```
use APP;
use APP\Interfaces;
use APP\Lib;
```

Now if you say just:

```
extends ActionController
```

PHP would not know if it is:

```
APP\ActionController or
APP\Interfaces\ActionController or
APP\Lib\ActionController
```

If you still wanted to extend it without `Lib` subspace you would need to do:

`use APP\Lib\ActionController;` first

Answer (score 1):

`use` is only there to *alias* namespaces or class names to *shorter names*. It's there to avoid having to repeatedly address all classes by their fully qualified name all the time:

```
$a = new \Foo\Bar\Baz\Quurx();
$b = new \Foo\Bar\Baz\Quurx();

// shorter:

use Foo\Bar\Baz\Quurx;

$a = new Quurx();
$b = new Quurx();
```

`use Foo\Bar` is shorthand for `use Foo\Bar as Bar`. So, you're creating an alias `Bar` which really resolves to the full name `\Foo\Bar`. Since `APP\Interfaces` doesn't resolve to any particular interface in your case, just using `implements Interfaces` wouldn't mean anything. And if you just used `implements ControllerInterface`, it would be ambiguous which namespace that resolves to. `\APP\Controllers\ControllerInterface`? `\APP\ControllerInterface`? `\APP\Lib\ControllerInterface`? It's just not clear and cannot be resolved automatically.

So, what you're doing is you're shortening `APP\Interfaces` to just `Interfaces`, and then refer to `APP\Interfaces\ControllerInterface` by just using the shorter `Interfaces\ControllerInterface`. You could be doing this to make it even shorter:

```
use APP\Interfaces\ControllerInterface;

.. implements ControllerInterface ..
```

Comment: Thank you! makes complete sense.